# Grow div size on pop up window resize with sticky footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have roughly the following layout:

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="content-inner-div">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-inner-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

Outer div contains two divs - content-inner-div where all the contents go, and footer-inner-div with several buttons.
Then I show this structure in jQuery popup window, like so:

```
var template =
    '<div class="outer-div">'
        + '<div class="main-inner-div">'
            + '</div>'
                + '<div class="footer-inner-div">'
                    + '</div'
                        + '</div'
                            + '</div';

this.popup = $(template);

var formulaDialog = $(this.popup).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    width: '300',
    minHeight: '100',
    closeText: '',
});

$(formulaDialog).dialog('open');
```

Now what I want is when I resize popup window - footer-div to stick to the bottom of the popup, and the content-div and it's content grow in size and occupy all available space in popup. Content-div may have very large content that won't fit the pop up - so I might need vertical scroll in content-div.

I have seen several similar questions on SO (namely [jQuery, change div height to automatically fill out remainder of screen if content isn't already larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221260/jquery-change-div-height-to-automatically-fill-out-remainder-of-screen-if-conte) and [set div height using jquery (stretch div height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541115/set-div-height-using-jquery-stretch-div-height?rq=1) ) but because I have no experience in JS, JQuery or CSS and in general I have trouple extrapolating those answers to my situation.

At this point I set maxHeight to content-div to 60% of the window height

```
$(window).height() * 0.6
```

so that when content-div does have large content modal pop up does not extent to the bottom of the screen. So a problem I get - is when I resize this content-div does not grow beyond it's maximum size.

How can I achieve nice resize with sticky footers without the mess I have now?

P.S. Tweaked a bit Vimal's answer to meet my question exactly - http://jsfiddle.net/7XBrb/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of what you want can be accomplished using plain ol' CSS except handling the resize bit (actually it does handle that, just not well enough to use it).

HTML with some junk content

```
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="content-inner-div">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rhoncus libero eu diam aliquet lobortis. Nunc ac turpis ac enim vehicula feugiat non ac nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris porta suscipit tellus, nec dapibus dui gravida eget. Vivamus interdum molestie dolor sit amet pharetra. Duis auctor facilisis scelerisque. Curabitur eget lacus augue, eget porttitor erat. Sed ornare augue vel elit pellentesque ut laoreet mauris tempus. Nullam accumsan, est sit amet sodales scelerisque, tortor ante fermentum leo, id aliquam metus purus tristique erat.

       Duis at arcu ac mauris auctor mollis placerat ac risus. Nunc porttitor bibendum tempus. Cras eget justo at dui sagittis lobortis. Aenean quam purus, dapibus a blandit at, elementum ut quam. Pellentesque pretium, metus tempus laoreet hendrerit, nunc neque pellentesque nisl, vitae aliquam felis libero sit amet erat. Proin ultrices sodales enim, in fermentum neque sagittis eu. Quisque scelerisque tincidunt iaculis. Donec bibendum ipsum quis nunc pretium sit amet adipiscing purus lobortis. Vestibulum id tortor et neque lobortis pellentesque sit amet eu velit. Sed interdum interdum nisl. Nulla hendrerit placerat suscipit. Mauris congue turpis sed nibh tristique semper. Nunc in sem vel nibh fermentum hendrerit. Pellentesque vel sapien diam. Sed ultricies tincidunt arcu, nec porttitor metus dapibus at. 
   </div>
   <div class="footer-inner-div">
     <p>blah</p>
   </div>
```

CSS. Set the initial height of the content div and the overflow property so that the scrollbars display when required

```
.content-inner-div { height: 60%; overflow: auto; }
.footer-inner-div { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; background-color: #F00; width: 100%;}
```

jQuery

- Use the resize event to detect changes in the size of the window
- Get the window's height
- Subtract the height of the `footer` div from it
- Subtract line height (to adjust for text in the last line)
- Assign it as the new height to the `content` div.

  ```
  $(function () {
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      $('.content-inner-div').css('height', ($(this).height() - $('.footer-inner-div').outerHeight() - parseInt($('.content-inner-div').css('line-height'), 10)) + 'px');
    });
  });
  ```

---

Edit: Forgot to add the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnALb/)